# How to tunnel all traffic through shadowsocks with v2ray plugin?

Tags: networking, iptables, vpn, bash, firewalld

Recently I was working ShadowSocks with V2ray plugin, but there was a problem since I encounter routing all the system traffic through ShadowSocks.

> The problem is I don't know to forward the whole network traffic of my system through that Shadowsocks with v2ray plugin established connection.

and

> Configurations are as below:

On the server-side, I use the below code to run the Shadowsocks in the terminal. (by installing shadowsocks-libev)

```sh
/usr/local/bin/ss-server -c /etc/shadowsocks-libev/config.json
```

the config is sth like this:

```
{
    "server":"SERVER_IP",
    "mode":"tcp_and_udp",
    "server_port":8080,
    "local_port":1080,
    "password":"PASSWORD",
    "timeout":600,
    "method":"chacha20-ietf-poly1305",
    "fast_open":true,
    "workers":20,
    "plugin":"v2ray-plugin",
    "plugin_opts":"server",
    "nameserver":"8.8.8.8"
}
```

On the client-side, I use the below command in the terminal. (by using it beside v2ray-plugin)

```sh
ss-local -s SERVER_IP -p 8080 -l 1080 -k PASSWORD -m chacha20-ietf-poly1305 --plugin v2ray-plugin
```

I use [SwitchyOmega](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/switchyomega/) to use on browsers like Firefox/Chrome and other Socks4 capable apps but not the whole system.

I'm wondering How to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time so you probably either solved this or lost interest. This is how I managed to do it https://dev.to/jadolg/tunneling-all-your-internet-connections-through-a-socks-proxy-4f5i
Basically, you will need badvpn-tun2socks in order to use a tun interface with the socks proxy. The rest is routing.